# Rails - Refile - IO error closed stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang, refile

I have three models Product, Image, Post.  Post and Product have many Images, which is polymorphic.  When I try to create either a new Product or Post with included images I get:

```
IOError (closed stream):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

The funny thing is: if I create the Product or Post without images, then come back and edit the model, I am able to upload images no problem.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :images, as: :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_attachments_for :images, attachment: :file
  has_many :line_items
end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :body
  has_many :images, as: :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_attachments_for :images, attachment: :file
end



class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  attachment :file
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
     @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes!(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :subtitle, :body, images_files: [])
  end

end
```

Here is /posts/_form.html.slim

```
.form
  = form_for @post do |post|
    = post.text_field :title
    = post.label :title
    = post.text_field :sub_title
    = post.label :subtitle

    div
      - @post.images.each do |image|
        .photo
          = attachment_image_tag(image, :file, :fill, 150, 150)
          div
            = check_box_tag "images_ids[]", image.id, false, :id => "image_#{image.id}"
            label remove
      div
        = post.attachment_field :images_files, multiple: true
      label Photos

    .edit-section
      label Body
      = post.text_area :body, :class => "edit", :style => "display: none"
      .field.editable[contenteditable="true" data-field-id="body"]
        - if @post.body?
          = @post.body.html_safe
        - else
          p
            | Body goes here
    .button-box
      = post.submit :class => "button primary"
      = link_to "Cancel", :back, :class => "button cancel"
```